# Unbiased estimator of $ 1 + \mu^{2}$ from a Normal population

Tags: self-study, expected-value, unbiased-estimator

> Question: If $ x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3},...x_{n}$ is a random sample from a $Normal$ $population$ $N(\mu,1)$ then  what is the unbiased estimator of $ 1 + \mu^{2}$ ?

I began finding the mean and variance of $X$

$$E(X) = \mu \  , \ Var(X) = 1$$

And the expectation of $X^{2}$  is

$$  E(X^{2}) = 1 + \mu^{2} $$

Hence is the unbiased estimator of $ 1 + \mu^{2}$ =  $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}$ ?

Is my method and solution correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any function of the data is called an estimator. There is no such thing as "THE" estimator of a quantity. Various estimators can have different properties.

You have shown (correctly) that your estimator $\tfrac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2$ is unbiased for $1+\mu^2$. You could consider other estimators and they may have different properties (e.g. smaller or larger variance).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I had meant unbiased estimator

Comment: In general there could be many unbiased estimators as well. In mathematical language you have shown that $T_1=\sum x_i^2$ is AN unbiased estimator of $1+\mu^2$. To say it is the unique unbiased estimator you would have to prove uniqueness (assume $T_2$ is an unbiased estimator, show that $T_2=T_1$).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the properties of a [non-central chi squared distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) to construct a non-biased estimator from the sum $$S_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

This sum $S_1$ has the mean $n+n\mu^2$. So $S/n$ will have the mean $1+\mu^2$, and is indeed an unbiased estimator.

---

A more efficient estimator (an estimator with lower variance) is to be made with $S_2 = \left( \sum x_i \right)^2$. If we scale this like $\frac{1}{n} S_2$ it will be distributed as non central chi squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom and mean $1+n\mu^2$.

This distribution for $\frac{1}{n} S_2$  has a lower variance than the case with $S_1$. You can verify this easily based on the lower mean and lower degrees of freedom (and the variance is a function of both of those).

So, the estimator $\frac{1}{n^2} S_2 + 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ will be a more efficient estimator.

---

The last solution is an estimator. And like bdeonovic stresses in his answer it is not *the* estimator.

However, there is a type of estimator which is unique and that is the minimum variance unbiased estimator (MVUE).

The estimator $\frac{1}{n^2} S_2 + 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ is *the* MVUE.

This is because it is a function based on the complete and sufficient statistic $\sum x_i$. See also the [Lehmann Sheffé theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem).

Comment: Thank you. What about **M.L.E** method? Is that also a good option in finding the unbiased estimator?

Comment: @Kalvin Be talking about *the* unbiased estimator  - recall that there are many unbiased estimators! For example, it may not be a very "good" estimator in other senses, but if we throw most of our sample in the bin and stick to the estimator $X_1^2$, is that biased? ;-)

Comment: The MLE is usually biased, meaning that for most parametrisations, it is not unbiased.

Comment: But if you can find a function of the MLE such that the output of the function becomes unbiased then you have an unbiased estimator. Like the example in the answer $\hat \mu = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is the MLE for $\mu$ and $1+ \hat \mu^2$ is the MLE for $1 +\mu^2$. If you correct it into  $1+ \hat \mu^2 - 1/n$ then it is unbiased.

Comment: This makes a great segway to why we divide by $n-1$ in the estimator for the standard deviation rather than by $n$ (unbiased estimator vs biased MLE). Like 3 weeks of standard inference semester 1 packed into this QA.